# show parameters of running kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

I would like to see with what parameters the running kernel has been started. i.e., I mean those parameters that are specified with the `append` option, such as `ipv6.disable=1` or `rootfstype=ext2`

Is there a way to display these options on a running system ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Very simple:

```
cat /proc/cmdline
```

From `man proc`:

```
/proc/cmdline
  Arguments passed to the Linux kernel at boot time.  Often done via a boot
  manager such as lilo(8) or grub(8).
```